# Unable to export the pivot table data as csv / excel from ShinyApp using rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, export-to-csv, shinyapps, rpivottable

I'm using rpivotTables Shinyapp to export the pivottable data as csv, excel, pdf using buttons (I don't want to export the actual data). The data is shwon in the image. However i'm unable to do so, can't figure out the reason due to my limited knowledge. I shall be really thankful for the help.

Kind regards

[image: need to save this out put data]

**My code :**

```
library(rpivotTable)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(shiny)

#ui
ui = fluidPage(
radioButtons(inputId="format", label="Enter the format to download", 
choices=c("none", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "copy"), selected="none"),

fluidRow( rpivotTableOutput("pivot")))


#server
server = function(input, output) { 


output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable( rpivotTable::rpivotTable( rows = c( 
"vs"),cols=c("carb"),vals =  "mpg", aggregatorName = "Sum",rendererName =  
"Table",width="50%", height="550px",
{
data <- mtcars

if(input$format =="csv") {
write_csv( data, 'data.csv')

} 
if (input$format=="excel") {
write.xlsx(data, "data.xlsx")
} 

data
}))}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting a pivot table with 'vs' as row and 'carb' as column with 'mpg' as values. Also getting names 'csv, excel, pdf, copy' but not functional. You can try running the codes mentioned

Comment: Anyone with a solution? Its a bit urgent guys. I shall be grateful for your guidance :)

Comment: You want buttons correct?

Comment: Hi @Chabo, i have updated the codes, i just want to save the output generated by pivot table as csv / excel.